# Style is not re-rendering on React Native

Tags: android, css, react-native

I have a problem with React-Native

my state: *Windows 10 - Hyper V, Visual Studio Emulator Android.*

I have an Component on my page (which is displayed where i click).

When I click, the Coordinate are send in the component.

```
< ClickAnimation x = {item.x} y = {item.y} />
```

The component have first the following:

```
state = {
    scaleAnim: 2
};
```

And When I click a second time, this.state.scaleAnim is changed to 0.001

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.x != this.props.x) {
        this.setState({scaleAnim: 0.001})
    }
}
```

And That is rendering:

```
render() {
        if (this.state.scaleAnim) {
            return <Animated.View
                key={this.props.y * this.props.x}
                style={{
                zIndex: 10,
                borderColor: "blue",
                borderRadius: 400,
                borderWidth: 1,
                position: "absolute",
                top: this.props.y,
                left: this.props.x,
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                backgroundColor: "red",
                transform: [
                    {
                        scaleY: this.state.scaleAnim
                    }, {
                        scaleX: this.state.scaleAnim
                    }
                ]
            }}>
                <Text>{this.state.scaleAnim}</Text>
            </Animated.View>
        } else {
            return <View/>
        };
    }
```

With this code, I have the following thing:

[image: The Style doesn't re-redender]

The setState changes the value because the text changes. But not the style applied.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it might be related to FB bug https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6278 - try setting scale to `0.1` or `0.01` and experiment when it still works for you and when it breaks.

Comment: Oh man!! I have seen this issue on github and this is why I have write 0.001 and not 0  ... And with 0.01 this is working. Thanks !!  Really strange that it's working with 0.01 and not 0.001

Comment: my guess is if your view dimensions multiplied by scaling factor is less than 1px, it does nothing (how original size). glad to help.